# Sitemap to use HTTPS - Magento

Tags: magento, sitemap

I am currently experiencing some problems with my Google search implementation due to a recent change to HSTS for my entire shop.

How can I create a Google sitmeap in Magento which uses the `'https://'` links instead of `'http://'` ?

I have already deleted my sitemap and generated a new one. It still suses http:// links.

In Google search console I see that only 8 of my 45 sites have been indexed so far..

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you tried re-indexing your site and generating a new sitemap?

Comment: Yup, tried both. Still http:// used

Comment: What are the Base Secure and Base UnSecure URLs set to ?

Comment: `http://url.de` and `https://url.de`

Answer (score 1):

The sitemap links are generated using the {{unsecure_base_url}}. Make sure you change this value from http://yoursite.com to https://yoursite.com found at System->Configuration->Web Unsecure Base URL. Also, make sure both Use Secure URLs in Frontend and Backend options are set to "Yes".